# Quartz Job does not excute when I invoke triggerJob

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz

The task of job is simple, just output the time in console. I need a button for excuting the logic immediately.

XxxService.class

```
    @Override
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public void run(Long[] jobIds) {
        for(Long jobId : jobIds){
            ScheduleUtils. run(scheduler, this.getById(jobId));
        }
    }
```

ScheduleUtils.class

```
    public static void run(Scheduler scheduler, ScheduleJobEntity scheduleJob) {
        try {
            JobDataMap dataMap = new JobDataMap();
            dataMap.put(ScheduleJobEntity.JOB_PARAM_KEY, scheduleJob);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()+"need hello..."+new Date());
            scheduler.triggerJob(getJobKey(scheduleJob.getJobId()), dataMap);
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            throw new RRException("run fail", e);
        }
    }
```

MyJob:

```
@Data
@Component("HelloJob")
public class HelloJob extends CustomJob {

    public String jobDescription = "演示Job";

    @Override
    public void run(String params) {
        System.out.println(
                Thread.currentThread() +"hello..."+new Date() + "params: " + params);
    }

}
```

When I add *@Transactional* on the *run(Long[] jobIds)*, the job does not run immediately and often run delay 15~20 seconds.

```
Thread[http-nio-8500-exec-1,5,main]need hello...Mon Jun 27 12:55:02 CST 2022

2022-06-27 12:55:24 INFO  [bear] QuartzScheduler_BearScheduler-DESKTOP-521BOOH1656305645549_MisfireHandler org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore Handling 1 trigger(s) that missed their scheduled fire-time.
Thread[BearScheduler_Worker-3,5,main]hello...Mon Jun 27 12:55:24 CST 2022params: aaaa,bbbbbbb
```

When I delete *@Transactional* on the *run(Long[] jobIds)*, the job will run immediately.

```
hread[http-nio-8500-exec-4,5,main]need hello...Mon Jun 27 12:59:40 CST 2022
Thread[BearScheduler_Worker-6,5,main]hello...Mon Jun 27 12:59:40 CST 2022params: aaaa,bbbbbbb
```

Why my job is handled by MisfireHandler? Why the job can not run immediately when *@Transactional* on the method? If you know the reason,please help me. Thanks

Comment: With transactional you have 1 long transaction for which a commit will be issued after the for loop finished. Without it you have x inidividual transactions each for one jobid.

Comment: The method named *run* in *xxxService.class* can return immediately ,but  *run* of Job invoke delay

Comment: Again the transaction is committed after the method has run. That is also the point at which quartz sees the triggers.

Comment: How can i do if I stay *@Transactional* on the *run*

Comment: If you want them to run immediatly you need an individual transaction for each trigger. Else there will be a delay, depending on the size of the list this might lead to Quartz thinking it missed a trigger and will execute using the misfire handler.